# Unable to disable a button if button has class attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

I have four buttons and three of them have a class called "multiple". the reason for this is they would be worked on by a jquery function.

```
<input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" <?php set_button_status(1,'is_add') ?>><br/>
<input type="submit" class="multiple" id="publish" name="publish" value="publish"><br/>
<input type="submit" class="multiple" id="unpublish" name="unpublish" value="unpublish"><br/>
<input type="submit" id="trash" class="multiple" name="trash" value="trash" <?php set_button_status(1,'is_delete') ?>><br/>
```

The set_button_status(1,'is_add') and set_button_status(1,'is_delete') function will return the string "disabled" to disable the add and thrash buttons respectively if the condition is true. However, only the add button is etting disabled.

When I remove the class "multiple" to the other buttons "publish" and "unpublish", the "trash" can now be disabled.

Why can't I disable a button if it has other buttons with the same class? How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you show us `set_button_status` php-code?

Comment: Please share the jQuery function as well

Comment: @Gauthaman Sahadevan no jquery. I just use disabled attribute

Comment: Either a CSS or JavaScript is being applied on the class multiple which is stopping the disabled attribute. Please post those code which has the class involved.

Answer (score 0):

I created [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lc0wnob/) with your code, assuming both .php calls return 'disabled'. It renders both 'Add' and 'trash' buttons as disabled:

```
<input type="submit" id="add" value="Add" disabled><br/>
<input type="submit" class="multiple" id="publish" name="publish" value="publish"><br/>
<input type="submit" class="multiple" id="unpublish" name="unpublish" value="unpublish"><br/>
<input type="submit" id="trash" class="multiple" name="trash" value="trash" disabled><br/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above code in my PC and everything is fine.**(Without PHP)**

[image]

First You put ;(semicolon) at the end of every PHP statement.

And /> instead of just > at the end of every input tag.

Let me know the results after that.